# $_POST sometimes empty even though isn't when using edited_[taxonomy] hook

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to save some term meta for some custom fields I have added via the `[taxonomy]_edit_form_fields` hook, I then save the data from these fields on edit with the hook action `edited_[taxonomy]`.

For a few different reasons I'm deleting all term meta via wpdb with my prefix and then looping through `$_POST`, finding my prefixed form names and adding the term meta, this works fine on my local environment, but on another environment (and only occasionally) the adding of term meta does not happen, the `$wpdb` query still deletes all the term meta first.

It's almost like sometimes `$_POST` is empty, but I've caught when it happens and used `var_dump` on `$_POST` and can see the data is coming through, any help with why this might occasionally happen and potential code edits to stop this occurring?

My code is:

```
function save_my_taxonomy( $term_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( !empty( $_POST ) ) {

        // Delete all term meta with my term name (this ensures this if an option was previously populated and no longer is and isn't submitted such as checkboxes, the removal occurs)

        $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "DELETE FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}termmeta` WHERE `term_id` = %d AND `meta_key` LIKE %s;",
                $term_id,
                'my_taxonomy_name_%'
            )
        );

        // Loop all $_POST

        foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {

            // If my field

            if ( strpos( $key, 'my_taxonomy_name_' ) === 0 ) {

                update_term_meta( $term_id, $key, $value );

            }

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'edited_my_taxonomy_name', 'save_my_taxonomy' );
```

Comment: Note that by running a raw SQL query you've bypassed all the filters and actions and could see cache related issues, such as stale caches that would normally have been flushed. Which action are you using? `edited_my_term_name` looks unfamiliar is it a placeholder for something else?

Comment: @TomJNowell https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/ the last bit is my taxonomy name

Comment: Ah, there are times when a taxonomy may be edited that don't involve the term edit screen, how are you testing the emptiness of `$_POST`? Or is this the leading theory to explain missing term meta? Are you sure the `strpos` check is accurate? Can you include the code that prints the inputs?

Comment: @TomJNowell  after the empty $_POST check at the start I'm also actually doing a nonce check from a field, which validates okay to be able to run the SQL that deletes, if it was from another location this check would fail and not do the SQL deletes or updates. I can't really post the fields here there are a quite a few, they are just text/select/checkbox inputs with names with my prefix on.

Comment: it would be useful, you may be making a mistake you haven't realised, or not implemented it the expected way, or maybe it's fine and it prevents people going down the same avenues of investigation. It also gives people a better understanding and makes it easier to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think this was maybe the wpdb query was running slower than the adding of meta, I've replaced the wpdb query with a get terms, foreach, delete and this seems to have solved the issue @TomJNowell

Comment: WPDB doesn't do things in parallel so it's speed wouldn't cause this. If you have found a solution you need to post it below as the answer or the site will keep suggesting this question as not having an answer. Remember these are just the comments!